# Animated split-flap display

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I'd like to create an animated split-flap display using c# / wpf. I want it to look similar to the one, that can be seen in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwxHJS9s6UI), but without the 3D effect. As I don't have a lot experience with wpf, I'd like to know how I can implement a UserControl for a single animated letter.

Comment: If you are new to WPF you schould take a look at animations and storyboards on MSDN for this particular task. You can most likely just do it like you would in AE.

Answer (score 3):

Without 3d, you could do this with multiple images.

Idea #1 Think animated gif. Only, you would have a one set of images to flip from 1 to 2. Another set of images to flip from 2 to 3, etc...

See Option 2 at this site:
http://www.wpfsharp.com/2011/05/11/wpf-replacement-options-for-an-animated-gif

Then you would have the click start the storyboard, then end at a new image instead of the same image. The more images you have, the less choppy it will be.

Idea #2
My other idea would use a top and bottom image for each number. Bend the images with RenderTransform changes.

Give this a look. I got it halfway there for you:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="FlipNumberStoryBoard">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(SkewTransform.AngleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Img1Top">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="5"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="10"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="20"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="35"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="60"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="75"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="88"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="Img1Top">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="-2.01"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="-3.45"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="-5.55"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="-7"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="-8.75"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="-9.5"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="-8.25"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="Img1Top">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="0.90"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0.80"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0.60"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0.40"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0.20"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="0.10"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="0.01"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="Img1Top">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="2.5"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="5"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="10.1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="15"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="20"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="22.6"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="24.9"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)" Storyboard.TargetName="Img2Bottom">
            <EasingInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="1"/>
        </Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Img1Top">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(SkewTransform.AngleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Img2Bottom">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="-88"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9" Value="-75"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="-60"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.1" Value="-35"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.2" Value="-20"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.3" Value="-10"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.4" Value="-5"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="Img2Bottom">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="0.01"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9" Value="0.10"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.20"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.1" Value="0.40"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.2" Value="0.60"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.3" Value="0.80"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.4" Value="0.90"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="Img2Bottom">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="-9.121"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9" Value="-8.87"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="-8.564"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.1" Value="-7"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.2" Value="-5.438"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.3" Value="-3.5"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.4" Value="-2.001"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="Img2Bottom">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="-24.75"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9" Value="-22.5"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="-20.062"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.1" Value="-15.062"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.2" Value="-10"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.3" Value="-5.062"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.4" Value="-2.562"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Img2Bottom">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image x:Name="Img2Top" Source="Images/02top.png" Grid.Row="1" Width="70" Height="50" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="0,-1,0,0"/>
    <Image x:Name="Img1Top" Source="Images/01top.png" Grid.Row="1" Width="70" Height="50" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="0,-1,0,0">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
    <Image x:Name="Img2Bottom" Source="Images/02.png" Grid.Row="2" Width="70" Height="50" Visibility="Collapsed" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
    <Image x:Name="Img1Bottom" Source="Images/01.png" Grid.Row="2" Width="70" Height="50" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
    <Button Content="Next" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="223.5,5,0,0" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" Click="Button_Click" />
</Grid>
```

And then on click of the button, you can see the flip.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace RenderTransformExample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var storyboard = (Storyboard)this.Resources["FlipNumberStoryBoard"];
            storyboard.Begin();
        }
    }
}
```

Now hooking that up so it just loops through images is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ScaleTransform to achieve the animation, and some dependency properties to make the UserControl easy to use.

First, you have to display your letter in two halves, which can be done using these styles :

```
<Style x:Key="UpperHalf" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Courier New" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,1" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Border Height="{Binding ElementName=SizeRef,
                                                Path=ActualHeight,
                                                Converter={StaticResource HalfConverter}}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            CornerRadius="10,10,0,0"
                            Padding="10,0">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="LowerHalf" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Courier New" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Border Height="{Binding ElementName=SizeRef,
                                                Path=ActualHeight,
                                                Converter={StaticResource HalfConverter}}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            CornerRadius="0,0,10,10"
                            Padding="10,0">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                            <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Text="{Binding}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

Then to display two overlapping letters (the old one and the new one) :

```
<Grid>
    <!--  Hidden textblock, only used for measurement purpose  -->
    <!--  The border is here to set the total height of the display so that we can have a small space between the two halves  -->
    <Border Margin="0,1" Visibility="Hidden">
        <TextBlock Name="SizeRef"
                   Margin="10,0"
                   FontFamily="Courier New"
                   Text="{Binding ElementName=Root,
                                  Path=Letter}" />
    </Border>

    <ContentControl Name="Letter1Top"
                    Background="Gray"
                    Content="{Binding ElementName=Root,
                                      Path=Letter1}"
                    Style="{StaticResource UpperHalf}">
        <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform />
        </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
    </ContentControl>
    <ContentControl Name="Letter2Top"
                    Background="Gray"
                    Content="{Binding ElementName=Root,
                                      Path=Letter2}"
                    Style="{StaticResource UpperHalf}">
        <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform />
        </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
    </ContentControl>
    <ContentControl Name="Letter1Bottom"
                    Background="Gray"
                    Content="{Binding ElementName=Root,
                                      Path=Letter1}"
                    Style="{StaticResource LowerHalf}">
        <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform />
        </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
    </ContentControl>
    <ContentControl Name="Letter2Bottom"
                    Background="Gray"
                    Content="{Binding ElementName=Root,
                                      Path=Letter2}"
                    Style="{StaticResource LowerHalf}">
        <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform />
        </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

The properties used above are created in code behind :

```
public partial class SplitFlapLetter
{
    public SplitFlapLetter()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public char Letter
    {
        get { return (char)GetValue(LetterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LetterProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LetterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Letter", typeof(char), typeof(SplitFlapLetter), new UIPropertyMetadata(OnLetterChanged));

    private char Letter1
    {
        get { return (char)GetValue(Letter1Property); }
        set { SetValue(Letter1Property, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Letter1Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Letter1", typeof(char), typeof(SplitFlapLetter), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    private char Letter2
    {
        get { return (char)GetValue(Letter2Property); }
        set { SetValue(Letter2Property, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Letter2Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Letter2", typeof(char), typeof(SplitFlapLetter), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    private bool _isLetter1Active;

    private static void OnLetterChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var uc = d as SplitFlapLetter;
        if (uc == null) return;

        if (uc._isLetter1Active)
            uc.Letter2 = uc.Letter;
        else
            uc.Letter1 = uc.Letter;

        var sb = uc.FindResource(uc._isLetter1Active ? "GotoLetter2Animation" : "GotoLetter1Animation") as Storyboard;
        if (sb != null) sb.Begin();

        uc._isLetter1Active = !uc._isLetter1Active;
    }

    private readonly List<char> _letters = new List<char> { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' };

    private void OnClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Letter = _letters[(_letters.IndexOf(Letter) + 1) % _letters.Count];
    }
}
```

The Letter property is the only public one and there is a listener on its changes.
This listener sets Letter1 or Letter2 to the new value, changing at every run, so that the other property is still set to the old value.

It then starts one of the two storyboard defined in the UserControl resources :

```
<Storyboard x:Key="GotoLetter1Animation">
    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Letter1Bottom"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                        To="0" />

    <Int32Animation Duration="0:0:0"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="Letter2Top"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)"
                    To="2" />
    <Int32Animation Duration="0:0:0"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="Letter2Bottom"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)"
                    To="1" />
    <Int32Animation Duration="0:0:0"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="Letter1Top"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)"
                    To="1" />
    <Int32Animation Duration="0:0:0"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="Letter1Bottom"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)"
                    To="2" />

    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                        From="1"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Letter2Top"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                        To="0" />

    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.2"
                        Duration="0:0:0.2"
                        From="0"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Letter1Bottom"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                        To="1" />

    <Int32Animation BeginTime="0:0:0.4"
                    Duration="0:0:0"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="Letter1Top"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)"
                    To="2" />
    <Int32Animation BeginTime="0:0:0.4"
                    Duration="0:0:0"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="Letter2Top"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)"
                    To="1" />

    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.4"
                        Duration="0:0:0"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Letter2Top"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                        To="1" />
</Storyboard>

<Storyboard x:Key="GotoLetter2Animation">
    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Letter2Bottom"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                        To="0" />

    <Int32Animation Duration="0:0:0"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="Letter1Top"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)"
                    To="2" />
    <Int32Animation Duration="0:0:0"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="Letter1Bottom"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)"
                    To="1" />
    <Int32Animation Duration="0:0:0"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="Letter2Top"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)"
                    To="1" />
    <Int32Animation Duration="0:0:0"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="Letter2Bottom"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)"
                    To="2" />

    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                        From="1"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Letter1Top"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                        To="0" />

    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.2"
                        Duration="0:0:0.2"
                        From="0"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Letter2Bottom"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                        To="1" />

    <Int32Animation BeginTime="0:0:0.4"
                    Duration="0:0:0"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="Letter2Top"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)"
                    To="2" />
    <Int32Animation BeginTime="0:0:0.4"
                    Duration="0:0:0"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="Letter1Top"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)"
                    To="1" />

    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.4"
                        Duration="0:0:0"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Letter1Top"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                        To="1" />
</Storyboard>
```

There's probably some way to reduce this xaml and use only one storyboard that would uses the appropriate targets.

Answer (score 1):

I think that [this](http://rgramann.blogspot.ca/2009/08/retro-flip-clock-wpf-control.html) project could really give you a base for what you want to do.

Unfortunately, I don't see how this split-flap display could look well without 3D.

Good luck !